# API calls error on TestFlight (only with iPhone 11 Pro)

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, testflight

My project works well on development mode.
It also works on release mode.

And even works well on TestFlight below iPhone 11.
It only crashed on iPhone 11 with TestFlight.

It crashes when I call my own rails API on AWS EC2 instance.

Has anyone ever been in this kind of error?

It also works well on iPhone 11 Pro on my local but only crashed on TestFlight.

I'm using Alamofire for my rails api call.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question with useful details. Provide details about the crash and show relevant code and error messages.

Comment: If I could check error code then i wouldn't share this on here...I can't check error.So I 'm gong to setup Fabric or something like crashlystics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.
We can check TestFlight Bugs:

- open Xcode
- open menu Window/Organizer
- select your project
- there are 4 buttons on the top - Archives, Crashes, Energy, Metrics.

That it's.
You could check logs from Crashes.

[image]